# Google docs set cell value - date case

Tags: google-docs

I want to set cell value Google docs after begining of new month. My formula: `=if(TODAY=2014-11-01, "YES", "NO")` doesn't work. Can anybody help me?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Describe the error messages or bad results you're seeing.

Comment: The following error massage appears: "Error parsing formula" .

Answer (score 0):

OK, the problem has been solved. Google made modification without changing of documentation. `=if(TODAY()=2014-11-1; "YES"; "NO")`. It works.